# "Permission Denied" error ruins Selenium scraping

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver, web-scraping

I've been scraping a website using Selenium (Python Webdriver).  When I try to have it `click()` an option, I get a permission denied error.  Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 19, in <module>
    subjectOptions[1].click()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 45, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 194, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 153, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 147, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u"'Error: Permission denied for <http://localhost/scrape_test> to get property HTMLDocument.compatMode' when calling method: [wdIMouse::move]"
```

Here is the code that causes the problem.  I know for a fact that the option I'm trying to click exists (based on `print`):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait #available since 2.4.0
import time

# Create a new instance of the FireFox driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# go to the local version of the page for testing
driver.get("http://localhost/scrape_test")

# Find the select by ID, get its options
selectElement = driver.find_element_by_id("CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SUBJECT$65$")
subjectOptions = selectElement.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

# Click the desired option
subjectOptions[1].click()
```

I'm using Firefox 8.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using, and on what OS?

Comment: What does subjectOptions[] hold? **IF** it is related to js, try adding a delay of 1-2sec before the click

Comment: subjectOptions[1] holds `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x10eb6fb90>` .  subjectOptions is a list of such WebElements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's a webdriver bug.  The latest [log entry](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/javascript/firefox-driver/js/syntheticMouse.js?spec=svn15123&r=15123) from the programmer who last modified one of the selenium source code files says:

> This leads to permissions errors, which I've still been unable to
>   reduce:
>
> Error: Permission denied for http://www.finn.no to get property
>   HTMLDocument.compatMode' when calling method: [wdIMouse::move]

There is some discussion about the issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3018), [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2929) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2863).

According to the discussion it should work fine with Firefox 7.  Also, [this related issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2929) implies that the link is still clicked in spite of the error, so it might work inside a try/except.

Comment: Putting a try catch didn't seem to resolve the issue for me.  It goes past that part without exception but doesn't click them.

Comment: I did `try: option.click() except: pass`

Comment: Another solution would be to use [an older build of Selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/2.13.0).  (I think 2.13.0 should not have the same problem.)

Comment: I settled on simply switching to another driver.  Chrome and HTMLUNITWITHJS seem to do fine.

Answer (score 0):

For time being you can overcome with work around given [here](http://aboutselenium.blogspot.in/2012/02/handling-permission-denied-error-for.html)